# How to call an API Method from C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#

I have an API which I need to run two GET methods in order to create an automation for a process I have.

I need to create two functions:
 1. one that takes the JSON body from response and filter it to get my desired variables
 2.another one to generate a file with the variables that I got.

My current problem is how can I execute the get method as I've followed the MS default guide to calling the API but when I run the code, I get an error in output. Note that I have to pass some parameters along with the url and the extension of API method.

For example: 
I have a Distance learning platform and I need to return all the assessments lists from all courses available within. The current system provides me a course id along with all lectures id, which I can use in another method from API to retrieve all assessments from the course id followed by its own lectures id.

Here is my code:

PS, the json returns more stuff than courses, i've made all these classes to get the return for the method /api/admin/courses

EDIT: UPDATED CODE!
program.cs:

```
    class Program
    {
        public static string url_user;
        public static string auth_token;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digite a plataforma desejada");
            url_user = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Digite o Token do Administrador");
            auth_token = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
            RunAsync().Wait();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://" + url_user + "/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                Console.WriteLine("GET courses");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/admin/courses" + "/?auth_token=" + auth_token);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    courses course = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<courses>();
                    course_list list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<course_list>(course.course_id);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}", course.course_id, course.course_slug, course.lectures);

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

courses class:

```
public class course_list
    {
        [JsonProperty("transactions")]
        public List<courses> courses_list { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
    }
    public class courses
    {
        [JsonProperty("transactions")]
        public string course_id { get; set; }
        public string course_slug { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public bool is_paid { get; set; }
        public string objective { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public bool published { get; set; }
        public string certification { get; set; }
        public string published_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime published_unti { get; set; }
        public string target_audience { get; set; }
        public DateTime time_available { get; set; }
        public int workload { get; set; }
        public lectures lectures { get; set; }
        public category category { get; set; }
        public string logo_url { get; set; }
        public bool listed { get; set; }
        public int subscriptions_count { get; set; }
        public string[] topics { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator HttpClient(courses v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

example of json return:

```
{
        "course_id": "5936ce684dad4e0080ddd90a",
        "course_slug": "curso-teste-gratis",
        "title": "Curso Teste Grátis",
        "description": "Neste curso abordaremos os recursos de mídia, mais específicamente os vídeos e como eles interagem na plataforma.",
        "is_paid": false,
        "objective": "Treinar &nbsp;utilização de vídeos",
        "price": null,
        "published": true,
        "certification": "",
        "published_at": "2017-06-06T12:57:28.000-03:00",
        "published_until": null,
        "target_audience": "interessados na plataforma. entusiastas",
        "time_available": null,
        "workload": 0,
        "lectures": [
            {
                "lecture_id": "5936cf257c31a4003a034d23",
                "lecture_slug": "videos-01",
                "title": "Vídeos 01",
                "description": "Nesta Aula iremos utilizar os recursos de vídeos",
                "is_free": false,
                "published": true,
                "published_at": "2017-06-07"
            },
            {
                "lecture_id": "593acfb84dad4e003f0b900e",
                "lecture_slug": "video-com-legenda",
                "title": "Video com Legenda",
                "description": "",
                "is_free": false,
                "published": true,
                "published_at": "2017-06-23"
            },
            {
                "lecture_id": "594d3fa6ad695700718acb16",
                "lecture_slug": "pesquisa-teste",
                "title": "pesquisa teste",
                "description": "",
                "is_free": false,
                "published": true,
                "published_at": "2017-06-23"
            },
            {
                "lecture_id": "595a6f90ad6957003690f096",
                "lecture_slug": "avaliacao-com-entrega",
                "title": "Avaliação com entrega",
                "description": "Checar avaliação com entrega",
                "is_free": false,
                "published": true,
                "published_at": "2017-07-03"
            },
            {
                "lecture_id": "595d52b658cd78004c9efc63",
                "lecture_slug": "aula-extra",
                "title": "aula extra",
                "description": "asdasdasd",
                "is_free": false,
                "published": true,
                "published_at": "2017-07-05"
            },
            {
                "lecture_id": "595d5333493a260070273e16",
                "lecture_slug": "aula-extra-2",
                "title": "Aula extra 2",
                "description": "teste aula extra 2",
                "is_free": false,
                "published": true,
                "published_at": "2017-07-05"
            },
            {
                "lecture_id": "595e9f4f78509000382f3caf",
                "lecture_slug": "pdf-gigante",
                "title": "PDF gigante",
                "description": "Livro da Hi English",
                "is_free": false,
                "published": true,
                "published_at": "2017-07-06"
            },
            {
                "lecture_id": "595ea11f7c31a4004b2d1a81",
                "lecture_slug": "pdf-pequeno",
                "title": "PDF pequeno",
                "description": "",
                "is_free": false,
                "published": true,
                "published_at": "2017-07-06"
            },
            {
                "lecture_id": "5964fcf1ad6957003a9b4099",
                "lecture_slug": "aula-publicada-nova",
                "title": "Aula publicada nova",
                "description": "Esta aula é para checar se o meu usuário receberá o e-mail de bloqueio de assinatura.",
                "is_free": false,
                "published": true,
                "published_at": "2017-07-11"
            },
            {
                "lecture_id": "596cd404ad695700838bd4dc",
                "lecture_slug": "f-rum",
                "title": "FÓRUM",
                "description": "Fórum do Curso.",
                "is_free": false,
                "published": true,
                "published_at": "2017-07-17"
            }
        ],
        "category": {
            "category_id": "593584fdad6957004cc4da13",
            "category_slug": "testes-47",
            "title": "testes"
        },
        "logo_url": "https://media.eadbox.com/system/uploads/course/logo/5936ce684dad4e0080ddd90a/photo.jpg",
        "listed": true,
        "subscriptions_count": 24,
        "topics": [
            "vídeos",
            "mídia"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: You should show the error, where you get it, and it also helps to read the repsonse as a string to help diagnose deserialization problems.

Comment: A little off topic, but there's no point in setting the BaseAddress if you are going to give an absolute url to the GetAsync() method.

Comment: It looks like you are re-using the `HttpClient` which is good, but the way you set the BaseAddress and DefaultRequestHeaders is bad if this is multi-threaded at all. Is it?

Comment: Well, thank you for your feedback guys, but my problem is how to make c# code execute the call and then get the body response, for example:

code:

main(){
user enter url and auth_token (this is my security check)
method_get_courses();
method_get_assessments();
}

method get_courses(){
<http request> url
insert parameters of api ("url" + "/api/admin/courses" + auth_token);

return <json body into somewhere>
}

The same for assessments with lectures and course id  with auth token
I know its very simple but its somekind of algorithm just so you can understand what i need

Comment: If you just want the returned json then do this: `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`. "...get the body response..." is a little too vague a question, `response.Content` is the body, it is up to you how to read it.

Comment: Guys I remade the entire thing, but now the only problem is that i need to  deserialize the json body as i'm having an error from it now.
<code>
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
         courses course = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<courses>();
         course_list list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<course_list>("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}");
         Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}", course.course_id, course.course_slug, course.lectures);
         
        }
<code>

Comment: @CaioVieira, you have to address someone with `@` if you want them to get a notification. You should update your question with the current version of your code and the complete error/exception. These problems are most often because the JSON does not match up to the class properties or the response has no JSON, just an error or something.

Comment: this is the response:
Inner Exception 1:
JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array into type <class type> because the type requires a JSON object  to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: @Crowcoder i've updated the code and posted the courses class for research. Thank you in advance. Now i'm getting this error:

WebException: The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.